# Grape API and OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, ruby-grape

I'm working on creating API for my rails application using Grape framework. I'm trying different authentication possibilities. Can someone give a simple example of using OAuth for authentication?

Comment: I'm rather late to the party but doorkeeper may be relevant: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi there here do you have an example

https://github.com/opperator/warden-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

More actual example you can find in [GrapeOAuth2 gem](https://github.com/nbulaj/grape_oauth2). All you need is to create 3 models that will represent your clients, tokens and resource owners, mount default endpoints and protect your API.

So create 3 models for used ORM and mount default OAuth2 tokens endpoint to your API:

```
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json
    prefix :api

    helpers GrapeOAuth2::Helpers::AccessTokenHelpers

    # What to do if somebody will request an API with access_token
    # Authenticate token and raise an error in case of authentication error
    use Rack::OAuth2::Server::Resource::Bearer, 'OAuth API' do |request|
      AccessToken.authenticate(request.access_token) || request.invalid_token!
    end

    # Mount default Grape OAuth2 Token endpoint
    mount GrapeOAuth2::Endpoints::Token

    # ...
  end
end
```

Available routes:

```
POST /oauth/token
POST /oauth/revoke
```

And then protect required endpoints with `access_token_required!` method:

```
module Twitter
  module Resources
    class Status < Grape::API
      before do
        access_token_required!
      end

      resources :status do
        get do
          { current_user: current_resource_owner.username }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Take a look at the README for  more detailed examples (simple one and customizable).